# Passing input values to Dialog Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-material

I am implementing the dialog component of material2 and faced this issue:

I want to make a generic dialog for all the confirmation type of messages, where developer can input the text to the dialog as per the business requirement. But as per the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog) there are no such provisions. Do we have a work around for the same, or I should post it as a feature request on github?

```js
export class ConfirmationDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() confirmationText: string;
  @Input() confirmationTitle: string;
  @Input() confirmationActions: [string, string][] = [];

  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ConfirmationDialogComponent>) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Calling like this:

```js
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent);
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @yurzui Added the code

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205593/working-example-of-angular-2-0-material-mddialog-with-angular-2-0/40185852#40185852 See step 8

Comment: Thanks @yurzui, We had a discussion over there as well. I totally missed it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

open will give you the component instance , means you can inject what ever you want to it like this :

```
openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog);
    let instance = dialogRef.componentInstance;
    instance.text = "This text can be used inside DialogOverviewExampleDialog template ";
    console.log('dialogRef',dialogRef);
  }
```

Then obviously inside the DialogOverviewExampleDialog template you can do :

```
   this is the text {{text }}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8k5k57xrFXKyL9bm1OtS?p=preview)

What I would normally do, I'd create a configuration object which my Component understands and then I'll pass this when opening the modal :

```
 private config = {
    title :"Hello there ",
    text :"What else ? "
 };

 openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog);
    let instance = dialogRef.componentInstance;
    instance.config = this.config;
    console.log('dialogRef',dialogRef);
  }
```

And then inside the modal component :

```
<div class="my-modal">
   <h1>{{config.title}}</h1>
   <p>{{config.text}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank for this. I needed to pass the parameters before initializing the component. There is another thread for this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40648252/how-can-i-pass-a-service-variable-into-an-angular-material-dialog

Comment: Worked perfectly bro, cheers